# I have issues with AJAX data variable. Getting Error 500

Tags: php, ajax

I get error 500 on the POST method. I don't really understand the data variable as I am following a tutorial.This is the jQuery script:

```
    var userLoggedIn = '<?php echo $userLoggedIn;?>';
    console.log('Hey There');
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#loading').show();

        //Original ajax request for loading first posts
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Heey");
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('.posts_area').html(data);

            }
        });

    });

    </script>
```

And here is the linked ajax_load_posts.php file:

````
include '../../config/config.php';
include '../classes/User.php';
include '../classes/Post.php';

$limit = 10; //Number of posts to be loaded per call

$posts = new Post($con, $_REQUEST['userLoggedIn']);
$posts->loadPostsFriends($_REQUEST, $limit);
?>```
````

Comment: have you tried debugging? Error 500 is a server error. Do you get that at the success function?

Comment: What does the servers error log tell you about the 500 error?

Comment: @Dave I guess this is it, I am not sure. It's shown in var/log/syslog. May 21 15:37:26 robert-ThinkPad-E470 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3757]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (19256262) is greater than comparison timestamp (19256260).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
May 21 15:37:26 robert-ThinkPad-E470 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3757]: Window manager warning: 0x2400001 (● index.ph) appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 19256262.  Working around...

Comment: The web servers log is where the error is not the general servers log. Sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: @Dave I got the solution. It was a typo in the called function. Thanks for your time.